# Strcpy in c++ doesn't work

Tags: c++

Can anyone tell why strcpy in this code returns an empty string?

```
#include <iostream>

char* strcpy(char* dest, const char* from) {
    for ( ; *from; dest++, from++) {
        *dest = *from;
    }

    return dest;
}

int main() {
    char a[] = "aba";
    char b[] = "hello";
    std::cout << strcpy(a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler I'm using is GNU G++11 4.9.2

upd: this doesn't work either
    #include

```
char* strcpy(char* dest, const char* from) {
    for ( ; *from; dest++, from++) {
        *dest = *from;
    }

    *dest = '\0';

    return dest;
}

int main() {
    char a[] = "abaaa";
    char b[] = "hello";
    std::cout << strcpy(a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your destination isn't even big enough to hold the string.

Comment: and you don't even put a null terminator !!

Comment: (Also, you return a pointer to one past the last character written)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using temp pointer:

```
char* strcpy(char* dest, const char* from) {
    char *tmp = dest;
    for ( ; *from; tmp++, from++) {
        *tmp = *from;
    }
    *tmp = '\0';

    return dest;
}
```

Also consider allocate memory for the dest with appropriate number of characters.

Comment: Thanks a lot, using temp helped

Answer (score 0):

The function and the program itself are invalid.:)

For example array `a` can not accomodate all characters from array `b` because its size is less than the size of `b`. (The size of `a` is equal to 4 while the size of `b` is equal to 6)

```
char a[] = "aba";
char b[] = "hello";
```

So the call `strcpy(a, b)` in this statement

```
std::cout << strcpy(a, b);
```

results in undefined behaviour.

As for the function then it does not copies the terminating zero from the sourse string to the destination string. And it does not return pointer to the first character of the destination string because inside the function pointer `dest` is changed (it was increased)

The correct function can look like

```
char* strcpy( char* dest, const char* from ) 
{
    char *p = dest;

    while ( *p++ = *from++ );

    return dest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of incrementing dest and from in the loop, try this:

```css
char *StrCpy (char *dest, const char *from){

 int i=0;
 for (i=0;i<strlen(from);i++){
  *(dest+i) = *(from+i);
 }
 *(dest+(strlen(from)))='\0';
return dest;
}
```